# Let $a$ have order $k$ modulo $n$. If $\gcd(h, k) = 1$, then show that $a^h$ also has order $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is my attempt but I am not able to proceed smoothly

Since $\gcd(h, k) = 1$, we have $1=hx+ky$ for some integers $x,y$.

$(a^h)^k = (a^k)^h \equiv 1\pmod{n}$

Lets suppose the order of $a^h$ is $r$, then 
$a^{hr}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$

Not sure where to go from here... Any help is appreciated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ has order $k$ and $a^{hr} \equiv 1\pmod{n}$, we have $k \vert hr$. Since $\text{gcd}(h,k) = 1$, we have $k \vert r$.

On the other hand, since $a^h$ has order $r$ and $(a^h)^k \equiv 1\pmod{n}$, and hence $r \vert k$.

We conclude that $r = k$.

Answer (score 1):

There exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $1=hx+ky$. Thus
$$a=a^1\equiv (a^h)^x(a^k)^y\equiv (a^h)^x\pmod{n}.$$

So $a$ is congruent to a power of $a^h$, and of course $a^h$ is congruent to a power of $a$. It follows that they have the same order.

Comment: That looks really short! Thank you! so is it always the case that $a$ and $a^h$ will have same order if $a\equiv a^{hx}$ ?

Comment: Yes. Because if $(a^h)^r\equiv 1$, then $(a^{hx})^r \equiv 1$, that is, $a^r\equiv 1$. And it is clear that if $a^r\equiv 1$ then $(a^h)^r \equiv 1$.

Comment: Ahh right, makes perfect sense xD ty!